# Unable to import 'progressbar2' library

Tags: python, python-3.x, progress-bar

I'm a newbie in python, and I was trying to use python library `progressbar2` in my code.

I tried installing the library with `conda` command to make sure it's installed in the anaconda environment, and I'm using VS code and it's set in the same environment too, so when I tried to import this library in my code with:

```
from progressbar2 import *
mselection = float(input("Method number : "))
while not 1 <= mselection <= 2:
  print("Invailed value")
  mselection = float(input("Method number : "))
else:
  if mselection == 1:

    area = float(input("Area: "))
    xyratio = float(input("X/Y Ratio: "))
    y = (area/xyratio)**(1/2)
    x = (area*xyratio)**(1/2)
    values = {'x':x,'y':y}
    values['o_data'] = [area, xyratio]
    print("The hight and weidth needed to create:-\nA rectangle with area {0[o_data][0]:^10}\nThe ratio between them {0[o_data][1]:^10}\nIs({0[x]:^10},{0[y]:^10})\nFor X= higth and Y= weidth.".format(values))
    input()

  elif mselection == 2:

    def result(y=0, i=0, ratio=1):
      return print(f"Y= {y:<20} X= {i:<20} Ratio= {xyratio}")

    area = float(input("Area: "))
    xmin = float(input("Xmin: "))
    xmax = float(input("Xmax: "))
    step = float(input("Step: "))
    include = str(input("Include: "))
    i = xmin
    pbar = p
    widgets = ['Test: ', Percentage(), ' ', Bar(marker='0',left='[',right=']'),
           ' ', ETA(), ' ', FileTransferSpeed()] #see docs for other options
    pbar = ProgressBar(widgets=widgets, maxval=((xmax-xmin)*(1/step)))
    pbar.start()
    while i <= xmax:
      y = area/i
      xyratio = str(i/y)
      if include in xyratio:
            result(y=y,i=i,ratio=xyratio)
      i = i + step
      pbar.update()
      if i == 0:
        i = 1 
  pbar.finish()
  input()
```

I get this error:-

```
{"resource": "/C:/Users/User/Desktop/Rectangle higth and weidth calculator.py",
    "owner": "python",
    "code": "import-error",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Unable to import 'progressbar2'",
    "source": "pylint",
    "startLineNumber": 2,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 2,
    "endColumn": 1
}
```

At first I faced the problem where I had not installed the library yet, so when I installed it and expected everything to work correctly, I got new error.

I'm using python 3.7.0.

Comment: whar new error? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: I added the full error

Comment: you may have two python installed. One with installed module and second which runs your code.

Comment: Anaconda installed everything for me, and all libraries is on it's environment folder, i didn't installed anything manually

Comment: it doesn't look like Python/Anaconda error but rather VSCode problem - and maybe pylint problem.  Run code without VSCode to see if it has problem to use 'progressbar2"

Comment: I tried to excute the code with python.exe and the cmd hanged immediately

Comment: When i remove everything related to this library, it works fine

Comment: do you have anything else in code except `import progressbar2` when you run in cmd ?

Comment: I will post the full code now

Comment: on [progressbar2 page](https://pypi.org/project/progressbar2/) you can see problems with other IDE - like IDLE, PyCharm. Maybe author of this module could help.

Comment: I see, but VS code isn't included, i will try spyder now and see

Comment: If I check correct documentation then it has name `progressbar2` with number "2" but you have to `import progressbar` without number "2"

Comment: No i have it with 2, i just posted the full code, have a look at it, the first line

Comment: in documentation pip uses with 2 but code uses without 2. I installed `pip install progressbar2` and I have to import `progressbar` without 2. Maybe this is problem - maybe you have to import without 2

Comment: I tried it, the error gone but i got this new one:-

Comment: Undefined variable 'p'

Comment: error shows you even in which line you have error so check it. I don't know what you try do to in `pbar = p`

Comment: You should first test same simple example from documentation.

Comment: I removed that line and it worked perfectly! thanks alot

Comment: Can you add this as answer so i can mark it as the solve?

Comment: I added answer few seconds ago :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This module has name `progressbar2` with number `2` and you install it with

```
pip install progressbar2
```

but in code it uses name without `2`

```
import time
import progressbar

for i in progressbar.progressbar(range(100)):
     time.sleep(0.02)
```

Example from [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/progressbar2/)

Answer (score 0):

If you've tried

conda install progressbar2

then go for the pip install

pip install progressbar2

[Note: if you don't have "pip" installed then go through this link in order to install pip https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AVCcFyYynQY ]

[If it doesn't works then provide more detailed error message.]

Comment: I installed it with pip and still getting the same error, how could i get you a more detailed error message?

Comment: easy_install progressbar2

i've gone through progressbar2 docs, they are suggesting to install through pip or easy install

Comment: I just tried the easy_install method, but the error still remaining

Answer (score 0):

use 
in linux

```
$ sudo pip install progressbar2
```

in windows run cmd as admin and

```
pip install progressbar2
```

Comment: I already done that, but still getting this error, the problem is that in the first VS code said that it couldn't find the library, and after i installed it, it then said it could not import the library

Comment: Try with upper case "P" for the library name